# Laravel adding foreign key and get Cannot add or update a child row error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

for this migration file as `payments` table i want to add other column with setting foreign key in other migration file, after run command in terminal i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laravel`.`#sql-1f1_42b`, CONSTRAINT `payments_product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DE
  LETE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `payments` add constraint `payments_product_id_foreign` foreign key (`product_id`) references `
  products` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

my `payments` migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('resnumber');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->boolean('payment')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and i want to add `product_id` column with this file:

```
class SetProductIdForeignToPayment extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index()->default(0);
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }
    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Mahdi, could you upvote helpful answers llike the last two ones. This realy motivates guys like me to give high quality answers.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yes sure, your pot upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `->default(0)` to `->nullable()`.